# Rails Helper to display rating in stars

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 6. Here's a piece that I wrote just to display number of stars. Obviously I am disgusted by my own code. How would you refactor?

```
# application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def show_star_rating(rating)
    zero_star_icon_name = "star"
    full_star_icon_name = "star_fill"
    half_star_icon_name = "star_lefthalf_fill"
    total_stars = []
    round_by_half = (rating * 2).round / 2.0
    (round_by_half.to_i).times { total_stars << full_star_icon_name }

    if round_by_half - round_by_half.to_i == 0.5
      total_stars << half_star_icon_name
    end

    if total_stars.size != 5
      (5 - total_stars.size).times { total_stars << zero_star_icon_name }
    end

    total_stars
  end
end

# show.html.erb
<% show_star_rating(agent_review.rating).each do |star| %>
  <i class="f7-icons"><%= star %></i>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of the [`Array.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-c-new), passing in the maximum number of stars you want to show, and defaulting all the stars to empty. Then, you can [`fill`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-fill) in the number of full stars you need. Then, finally, thanks to `Numeric`'s [`divmod`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod) returning either `0` or `1` for the number of half stars you need, you make one more pass and `fill` in the number of half stars you need:

```
module StarHelper
  EMPTY_STAR_ICON = 'star'.freeze
  FULL_STAR_ICON = 'star_fill'.freeze
  HALF_STAR_ICON = 'star_lefthalf_fill'.freeze

  def full_and_half_star_count(rating)
    (rating * 2).round.divmod(2)
  end

  def stars(rating, max_stars: 5)
    full_stars, half_stars = full_and_half_star_count(rating)

    Array.new(max_stars, EMPTY_STAR_ICON).
      fill(FULL_STAR_ICON, 0, full_stars).
      fill(HALF_STAR_ICON, full_stars, half_stars)
  end
end
```

Comment: Same as my answer on the [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59477682/rails-helper-to-display-rating-in-stars/59480841#59480841), but it seems more on topic here than over there, so adding it over on this side

Comment: I like the `fill` approach.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, you answer is a great first answer. Thank you for taking the time to port your answer across.

Comment: Thanks. I'd move the `full_and_half_star_count` private too.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if all those logic is meant to be in the ApplicationHelper. You could create a new helper file and move that logic.

As you have three constant values declared within the method body, you can move them outside as constants, and modify the value of `total_stars` depending on the conditions you have:

```
ZERO_STAR_ICON_NAME = "star"
FULL_STAR_ICON_NAME = "star_fill"
HALF_STAR_ICON_NAME = "star_lefthalf_fill"

def show_star_rating(rating)
  round_by_half = (rating * 2).round / 2.0
  total_stars = Array.new(round_by_half, FULL_STAR_ICON_NAME)
  total_stars += [HALF_STAR_ICON_NAME] if round_by_half - round_by_half.to_i == 0.5
  total_stars += Array.new(5 - total_stars.size, ZERO_STAR_ICON_NAME) unless total_stars.size == 5
end
```

- You can use `unless` whenever you have a `!=` condition to make the statement more clear.
- You can use `Array.new` to create a new array and sum (`+=`) it to the current value of `total_stars`.